# resize to fit the screen using css

Tags: html, version-control, screen, zooming, scale

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY4pG.png  <--- Not enough reputation to post images.

This is how my website looks without any browser zoom on a 27" screen.
I know about this but I dont know how to use it.

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+  */
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);   /* IE 9 */
-o-transform: scale(0.5);    /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
transform: scale(0.5);

offsetRatio = (ratio - 1) / 2;
```

So how do I make my site auto scale??

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this:

`width:100%;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp